# Will it possible to have in Jannah your own galaxy or universe?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, jannah, universe

It came my mind and I want ask that it is possible to wish or have your own galaxy or even your own universe in Jannah? as it possible that Jannah is located one multiverse or parallel universe? As Allah have promised that anything will be given.. So I want to ask that is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: None who is alive has seen jannah before and except the few information we have got via our Prophet's tradition which doesn't even give a hint of an answer for this question we can't even imagine what might or might not be there. Any answer would be speculative.

Answer (score 4):

There are probably hundreds of thousands of things you should be more concerned about right now than just the possibility of getting your own galaxy for whatever reason.

First you should know Allah, learn the basics of Islam and bring your knowledge in to practice. If you embark on this journey, I don't think you'll have time for a question like you have now.

Yes, there are many things a person can have in Jannah. However, we only know of what has been revealed through the Qur’an and the authentic narrations (ahadeeth) - e.g.: rivers, fruits, trees, palaces, spouses, etc. It would be dangerous waters to go into the subject if there's no revealed knowledge.

If a person is suffering from a severe ailment and is in pain, I don't think he'll worry about the neighbour's car blocking his gate or going to a restaurant for a dinner. Similarly if a person has just graduated from university he wouldn't wish to go back to the 10th grade to repeat. If a man has a beautiful and pious wife who loves him, I don't think he'll wish to be a kid again.

The point is that when you are in a certain stage, certain things won't happen to you. You won't think about certain things. For example, in Jannah, there's no death, wine is allowed and won't make you drunk, etc...

So whether or not this wish is a possibility or whether it will happen is not something you should worry about. Just try to live and die as a Muslim and that is good for you.

Comment: I like your answer. One must be striving for Jannah first instead of just thinking what will I get in Jannah.

Answer (score 2):

The width of garden of each believer in paradise is larger than all skies and earth:

> And hasten to forgiveness from your Lord and a garden as wide as the
>   heavens and earth, prepared for the righteous http://tanzil.net/#3:133

I do not know the science has discovered the size of skies or not. But indeed this size is larger than our galaxy and universe. Because our universe is only the first sky. And there are seven skies.

Also there is a verse saying in paradise there is anything a believer wishes. So simply a believer can wish a garden with such a size.

> Circulated among them will be plates and vessels of gold. And therein
>   is whatever the souls desire and [what] delights the eyes, and you
>   will abide therein eternally. http://tanzil.net/#43:71

But this verse does not mean all believers in paradise have such level of rewards. There are different levels and each level with special rewards.

Answer (score 1):

Your (and mine, and everyone's) main concern, rather the ONLY concern, should be how to get in Jannah. What will we have there, IF we get there is of secondary importance.

In Jannah, every person will be rewarded on 3 levels:

1. One's all instincts/desires etc. will already be fulfilled. *We cannot fully imagine this completely.*
2. Whatever one wants, will be given by Allah. *We cannot fully imagine this completely.*
3. The Actual reward in Jannah will be what no eye has seen, no ear heard and no one has even thought about. *Certainly, we cannot fully imagine this at all.* (There is a hadith about it, I'll find the reference.)

May Allah give us the strength to strive for Jannah. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

That is true. The hadith that mentions is [Sahih Muslim Book 20, Hadith 1883](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1883)

> .... Allah will say: "....  *You will have whatever your soul desires and whatever your eyes could delight in*" .....

Allah also says in [67:1](http://quran.com/67/1)

> Blessed is He in whose hand is dominion, and He is over all things competent

So, it is entirely possible to have whatever you want in Jannah(Heaven).

Answer (score 0):

To put things in context:

The galaxy that is inhabited by our solar system (that includes the Sun, our Earth, and myriad other planets) is some 100,000–120,000 light-years in diameter and contains 100–400 billion stars.  It may contain at least as many planets as well. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way).

Can you imagine that? There are more stars like our Sun within our "home" galaxy than there are humans on the planet. AND, that is just *our* galaxy.

So how many such *galaxies* has Allah created?

There are probably more than 170 billion galaxies in the observable universe. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy) Mind you, that's only the *observable* universe. What is beyond that may well be beyond our imagination.

That's almost 25 billion galaxies per person who is currently alive on Earth. And these galaxies may be "dwarfs," (with "only" just ten million stars). There are also giants with *one hundred trillion* stars, each orbiting their galaxy's own center of mass.

So I guess that Allah has created greater resources than what we as humans can ever ask for. Indeed, if the first of us and the last of us, the humans of us and the jinns of us, gathered together in one place and asked Allah for everything that our heart desires, and if Allah were to grant it to us, it would decrease the same amount as a needle decreases when it is dipped into the sea. [See Imam Nawawi's 40 Hadith, Hadith Qudsi 23: http://sunnah.com/nawawi40]

I think this should make it clear to you that when Allah says that He has infinite resources to give you, He really means it: we can see a small sampling of those within our observable universe.

I am also wont to think that Hell Fire may actually be very bright white stars. For instance,  it is reported that the Messenger of Allah (SAWS) said, "The Fire of Hell was burned for 1000 years until it became red. It was then burned for 1000 years till it became white. It was then burned for 1000 years till it became black. It is now intense black in color.” (Tirmidhi, Muwatta)

These stages actually describe the heat levels of various stars. For instance, our star, the Sun, is a yellow star, and red and yellow starts are among the coolest ones. Blue stars are hotter than these stars, followed by white stars which are extremely hot. The next level is extreme black, which implies intense heat that is unimaginable.

There are also hadeeth that describe how it will take several years drop to reach the bottom of Hell, which is not surprising, considering the size of these stars.

But then again, these are my assumptions where I try to correlate what we know empirically to what has been described in the Books of Hadith. And it is forbidden to do things like drawing the Fire of Hell or the Gardens of Paradise using our imagination since what the Qur'an and Hadith describe are far different from what we humans can ever imagine. At best, we can use the information presented here only as an indicator of Allah's Greatness and for us to get an idea of His vast creation and resources.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There will be much more. You want fun, drama, adventure, fantasy and what have you?  Sit back and imagine access to the greatest mysteries, dramas and adventures untold from Adam to the end of the world... Like how did God created the universe, how you survived from conception to your birth... Imagine knowing all those moments you cannot remember when you were an infant... Everything you can and cannot conceive will be at your fingertip to enjoy in jannat..  But make sure in this world you believe in God and never associate him with anything and do all good things and avoid all bad... That is your access to whatever you wish for there.

Credentials:
Ali Abubakar Sadiq, Recipient of Cambridge University award for journalist on science and religion

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that you’ll need to have your own galaxy in Heaven. Because, Heaven it is your 0.2 home where you can eventually Rest In Peace forever. But, you can see God and that should be enough for you, because by just seeing God directly, then this is the greatest blessing in Heaven, the greatest blessing is not Heaven, but seeing God directly is indeed a beautiful and the greatest blessing. This should be enough for you.

Logically speaking, if you were to wish to have an entire galaxy in Heaven, then what’s Heaven for? Once you’ll reach in Heaven, you won’t need anymore a galaxy.

If I were to be in Heaven, I would wish for simple things to have, like:

1. To have my own yard that grows all types of fruits and vegetables.
2. To have all members of my family from past and future to Heaven.
3. To R.I.P. in other words, to have relaxation.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In this world we are just like a little kid who is demanding for chocolates and toffees and a baby rattle to play with as compared to what will be available in paradise. Our thinking is confined in this world. There will be a lot more than that in paradise which will be beyond our imaginations...